# Dns.GetHostEntry.AddressList returning each IP Address twice

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use `Dns.GetHostEntry.AddressList` to get the IP addresses of systems on the network. The problem is that each IP is repeated twice in the AddressList.

for example if a system has only one IP Address like `192.168.1.1` the `Dns.GetHostEntry.AddressList` will have two entries both with the ip `192.168.1.1`

If the system has two IP addresses like `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.2`, `Dns.GetHostEntry.AddressList` will contain four entries repeating each IP twice.

This problem is happening for all the systems in our network.

Any Idea what could be the problem?

Here is the code :

`var myHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com")`

Comment: I've just tryed it and haven't had any issue with it. Can't you share your code?
What if you specify "8.8.8.8" as DNS server in your adpater settings? Maybe your problem comes from your DNS server

Comment: @patxy I've set my DNS to "8.8.8.8" and tried querying www.google.com, I still get each IP twice. Could this be related to IPv6? I'm using windows 8 and I have disabled IPv6

Comment: I also have IPV6 disabled. After having changed your DNS server, have you cleared your DNS cache? (CMD => ipconfig /flushdns)

Comment: And inside the console, what happens if you try the following command : "nslookup www.theHostYouWant.smthg"

Comment: @patxy Yes I have tried clearing the cache. I also tried `Dns.GetHostAddresses` but that is also returning each IP twice. `NSLOOKUP` is returning everything correctly so I don't think it could be related to DNS issues.

Comment: so it maybe related to your code. Sharing it might help to community to help you

Comment: @patxy I just edited my post and added the code.